# How To Capture Keypress Event inside Compose Email body(Mail Item) in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, keypress

I need to capture the **keypress event** when a user types the contents inside the mail body. When the user presses the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> the previous word has to be read from the compose mail body. How can this **keypress event** be captured within the compose mail window from the mail body?

Any suggestions or any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: JP, When a user presses spacebar inside compose mail body, the previous word has to be read and it has to check with the keyword which is present in the DB and if it matches a link has to appear for that word with the corresponding URL in the DB.

Comment: Did you have any luck getting this to work?  I'm looking for something similar with the "To..." field in the outlook compose window.

Answer (score 1):

There are [no exposed keypress events](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsto/thread/3e84cb9f-3423-4874-b24b-8fb9a0f678e5) in the [`Word.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document.aspx) you have access to via the [`Inspector.WordEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868196.aspx). In order to do this you would [need to access low-level WIN32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646168/175679) calls such as [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Here is an MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) describing the usage of [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and capturing **keypress events**.

Comment: Hi SilverNinja, Thanks for your reply. Will try it and update you soon.